# Vite 4.3 cant handle amcharts4

Tags: vite, amcharts4, vitest

After upgrading Vite to 4.3 I get this error when running test:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
at Module.__extends (C:\Dev\...\node_modules\tslib\tslib.es6.js:26:15)
at C:\Dev\...\node_modules\src\.internal\core\elements\Modal.ts:38:5
at C:\Dev\...\node_modules\@amcharts\amcharts4\.internal\core\elements\Modal.js:38:2
at VitestExecutor.directRequest (file:///C:/Dev/.../node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:328:5)
at VitestExecutor.cachedRequest (file:///C:/Dev/.../node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:186:14)
at VitestExecutor.dependencyRequest (file:///C:/Dev/.../node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:221:12)
at C:\Dev\...\node_modules\@amcharts\amcharts4\.internal\core\export\Export.js:5:31
at VitestExecutor.directRequest (file:///C:/Dev/.../node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:328:5)
at VitestExecutor.cachedRequest (file:///C:/Dev/.../node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:186:14)
at VitestExecutor.dependencyRequest (file:///C:/Dev/.../node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:221:12)
```

This is in my vite.config.ts:

```
test: {
setupFiles: ['vuetify.config.js', 'tests/unit/setup.ts'],
globals: true,
environment: 'jsdom',
deps: {
  inline: ['vuetify', '@amcharts/amcharts4'],
},
snapshotFormat: {
  escapeString: false,
  printBasicPrototype: true,
},
```

},

If I remove the deps. I get this error when running test:

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
C:\Dev\...\node_modules\@amcharts\amcharts4\.internal\core\export\Export.js:21

import { __awaiter, __extends, __generator } from "tslib";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: Any news ? I'm facing same issue-ish.